# Trouble linking ffmpeg example source code

Tags: gcc, ffmpeg

I managed to build ffmpeg and libx264 on my Ubuntu 11.10 machine from source.

I'm trying to work on the example source file decoding_encoding.c. The examples comes with a makefile, so I can just type in "make all" and it magically compiles and links everything. Now, I'm trying to compile and link from the command line but I can't seem to get it to link.

Here is the makefile:

```
# use pkg-config for getting CFLAGS abd LDFLAGS
FFMPEG_LIBS=libavdevice libavformat libavfilter libavcodec libswscale libavutil
CFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config  --cflags $(FFMPEG_LIBS))
LDFLAGS+=$(shell pkg-config --libs $(FFMPEG_LIBS))

EXAMPLES=decoding_encoding filtering metadata muxing

OBJS=$(addsuffix .o,$(EXAMPLES))

%: %.o
        $(CC) $< $(LDFLAGS) -o $@

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $< $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@

.phony: all clean

all: $(OBJS) $(EXAMPLES)

clean:
        rm -rf $(EXAMPLES) $(OBJS)
```

I can compile the source using this:

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include -c -o decoding_encoding.o decoding_encoding.c
```

When I try to link using this:

```
gcc -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -lavdevice -lavformat -lavfilter -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil -o decoding_encoding decoding_encoding.o
```

At this point, I get a huge list of 'undefined reference error'

```
decoding_encoding.o: In function `audio_encode_example':
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x25): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_encoder'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0xad): undefined reference to `avcodec_open'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x1ce): undefined reference to `sin'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x238): undefined reference to `avcodec_encode_audio'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x297): undefined reference to `avcodec_close'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x2a3): undefined reference to `av_free'
decoding_encoding.o: In function `audio_decode_example':
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x2f7): undefined reference to `av_init_packet'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `avcodec_find_decoder'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x359): undefined reference to `avcodec_alloc_context3'
decoding_encoding.c:(.text+0x379): undefined reference to `avcodec_open'
..... etc.
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Am I doing something wrong with my linker command? I've examined the makefile and I believe that I'm doing exactly what the makefile is....or am I?

Thanks,

Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-l` options should go after any other options.

Comment: I just tried this: gcc -Wall -o decoding_encoding -L/usr/local/lib -lavdevice -lavformat -lavfilter -lavcodec -lswscale -lavutil decoding_encoding.o     got the same result...

Comment: Sorry, I was inexact, the `-l` options should go after even non-option arguments.

Comment: Yup that was it. Thanks Tripleee! :)